# SQL 2 Tables one Date Group and sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guy's i need some help for my Chart.

I have 2 Tables "The money i will get" and "The money i pay" 
3 Fields (id, money, date)

my Two querys to get the Arrays for my Chart are:

```
SELECT date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m') as pDate1, date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%Y') as pDate2, date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m-%Y') as pDate3, sum(einnahmen.einnahmen) as pAmount FROM einnahmen GROUP BY pDate3 ORDER BY pDate2 ASC, pDate1 ASC

SELECT date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m') as pDate1, date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%Y') as pDate2, date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m-%Y') as pDate3, sum(ausgaben.ausgaben) as pAmount FROM ausgaben GROUP BY pDate3 ORDER BY pDate2 ASC, pDate1 ASC
```

and now i stuck at combining this two, the result should be 1st - 2nd but in the same format, grouped by month and year and sum the months

Edit (added table Structure and Data)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ausgaben`;
CREATE TABLE `ausgaben`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ausgaben` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 21 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Fixed;
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (1, 1149, '2017-05-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (2, 3116, '2017-06-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (3, 4493, '2017-07-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (4, 6438, '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (5, 2830, '2017-09-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (6, 0, '2017-10-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (7, 0, '2017-11-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (8, 0, '2017-12-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (9, 0, '2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (10, 0, '2018-02-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (11, 0, '2018-03-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (12, 0, '2018-04-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (13, 0, '2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (14, 0, '2018-06-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (15, 0, '2018-07-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (16, 0, '2018-08-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (17, 0, '2018-09-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (18, 0, '2018-10-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (19, 0, '2018-11-01');
INSERT INTO `ausgaben` VALUES (20, 0, '2018-12-01');
```

and Table 2

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `einnahmen`;
CREATE TABLE `einnahmen`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `einnahmen` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 23 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Fixed;
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (1, 0, '2017-05-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (2, 2850, '2017-06-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (3, 650, '2017-07-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (4, 0, '2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (5, 166, '2017-09-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (6, 990, '2017-10-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (7, 0, '2017-11-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (8, 0, '2017-12-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (9, 0, '2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (10, 0, '2018-02-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (11, 0, '2018-03-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (12, 0, '2018-04-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (13, 0, '2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (14, 6, '2018-06-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (15, 0, '2018-07-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (16, 0, '2018-08-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (17, 0, '2018-09-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (18, 4, '2018-10-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (19, 2, '2018-11-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (20, 1, '2018-12-01');
INSERT INTO `einnahmen` VALUES (21, 3000, '2017-10-02');
```

[Query 1 Einnahmen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVZnw.png)

[Query 2 Ausgaben](https://i.stack.imgur.com/735EX.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT p.pDate1,p.pDate2,sum(p.pAmount)
FROM 
    ((SELECT date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m') as pDate1, 
       date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%Y') as pDate2,
       date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m-%Y') as pDate3, 
       sum(einnahmen.einnahmen) as pAmount 
    FROM einnahmen GROUP BY pDate3 )    
UNION ALL    
    (SELECT date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m') as pDate1,
       date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%Y') as pDate2, 
       date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m-%Y') as pDate3, 
       sum(-ausgaben.ausgaben) as pAmount 
    FROM ausgaben GROUP BY pDate3)) p
GROUP BY p.pDate2,p.pDate1    
ORDER BY p.pDate2 ASC, p.pDate1 ASC;
```

Comment: Thx but i got the message "1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias" what means this :)

Comment: Try now, i forgot the alias

Comment: perfect but i forgot something, i need not the sum() of every month. i need "einnahmen" - "ausgaben"  for every month ^^

Comment: Ok, if you put a - in sum(-ausgaben.ausgaben), you will get a negative value, so you will get  "einnahmen" - "ausgaben". I have modified the query

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from 
(SELECT 
einnahmen.created_at,
date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m') as GETpDate1,
date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%Y') as GETpDate2,
date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m-%Y') as GETpDate3,
sum(einnahmen.einnahmen)
over (partition by date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m-%Y') 
order by date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%Y'),
date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m')) as GETpAmount
FROM einnahmen) as e
JOIN
(SELECT
ausgaben.created_at,
date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m') as PAYpDate1,
date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%Y') as PAYpDate2,
date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m-%Y') as PAYpDate3,
sum(ausgaben.ausgaben) 
over (partition by date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m-%Y') 
order by date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%Y'),
date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m')) as PAYpAmount
FROM ausgaben) as a
on a.ausgaben.created_at = e.einnahmen.created_at
```

Is it something like thid you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

```
select pdate1,pdate2,pdate3,pamount 
from(
    SELECT date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m') as pDate1, date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%Y') as pDate2, date_format(einnahmen.created_at, '%m-%Y') as pDate3, sum(einnahmen.einnahmen)     as pAmount 
    FROM einnahmen GROUP BY pDate3 ORDER BY pDate2 ASC, pDate1 ASC) x
union all
select pdate1,pdate2,pdate3,pamount 
from(
   SELECT date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m') as pDate1,     
     date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%Y') as pDate2, 
     date_format(ausgaben.created_at, '%m-%Y') as pDate3, sum(ausgaben.ausgaben) as pAmount 
   FROM ausgaben 
   GROUP BY pDate3 
   ORDER BY pDate2 ASC, pDate1 ASC)y
```